# Rails - javascript not using generated JSON as source

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I've got some javascript that uses JSON to create a timeline. I've got the JSON being generated using json_builder so that it is only populated with the current user's info. The JSON displays fine when you go to its URL, however when the URL is given to the JS, it can't find the data, so the timeline gets stuck on the loading screen.

Does the JSON not get generated when it is "visited" by the javascript? What can I do to remedy this so that the javascript is getting the right data? If you give the javascript a static JSON file to work with, it works fine.

Basically, what I think I need to do is have some way of the javascript to hold the json in a variable that it can then call as the source instead of a URL. Or can I get the json_builder to run within a javascript function?

I'm fairly new to rails, so you might have to spell it out a bit for me, but any help on how to fix this would be much appreciated, TIA.

Javascript:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                createStoryJS({
                    type:       'timeline',
                    width:      '800',
                    height:     '600',
                    source:     'users/<%= current_user.id %>/events.json',
                    embed_id:   'my-timeline'
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: yes it does. I've no idea why it works, but I've found a solution, its posted below. Thanks anyway :0)

Answer (score 0):

Should the source start with `/`?

```
source: '/users/<%= current_user.id %>/events.json'
```

Comment: sorry, my typo! Doesn't make a difference though :(

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why this works, but it does! I just needed to add ?callback to the end of the URL - i.e. :

```
source:     '/users/<%= current_user.id %>/events.json?callback',
```

This grabs the right data.